# Aligning table elements in a responsive email

Tags: email, alignment, responsive-design

I'm designing a responsive email, and I have two tables in one `<td>`. The second table is not top aligned in Outlook 2007 and 2010:

[image]

Both tables inside a `td` have a pixel width but rest of the tables inside these two tables have `width=%`.

I tried align left and right, as well as `style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"` but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I suspect it is due to Outlook using Word to render HTML and Word is getting confused and barfing up a page break.

I recommend placing each of the tables inside cells of a parent table. Then apply your style to the cells of the parent table. Note that "float" is generally bad to use in HTML for email, but since it's in a media query means it's safe to use.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {  
  .floatLeftResponse{
    width:100% !important;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="floatLeftResponse">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
          <td> <!---bla bla bla this is your left column content-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="floatLeftResponse">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
          <td> <!---bla bla bla this is your right column content-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```