# Repositioning table elements for responsive email design

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to adjust the table position that I have created here for responsive email:

Table 1 | Table 2

I put table 1 alignment as left so that on desktop both of these tables can sit nicely together in same line.

What I want to do on mobile is that the table 2 will move to the left and table 1 will move to the right still sitting on the same line.

Table 2 | Table 1

I tried to use float on media queries but no luck, any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually interested in simply having your two tables stack on top of each other. If that's the case, you are looking for something similar to this:

[Aligning table elements in a responsive email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422920/im-designing-a-responsive-email-as-i-have-two-table-in-one-td-second-table)

If I'm on the right track, let me know and I can provide more info.